# R notebook in Github

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, rnotebook

I have written a notebook in RStudio (R markdown document with output: html_notebook). I would like to display it in Github. Which is the best way?
I know that it is possible to change the output in github_document but the output is a bit different.

Comment: Directly related: [Display R notebooks on github](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1020); bottom line: sadly, not possible (yet)